# Using a user-defined class as template type and using it's non-static data members for decision making. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static

I have class like this :

```
class B{
public:
    const char* const getX() const {return X_;}
    const char* const getY() const {return Y_;}
    const char* const getZ() const {return Z_;}

protected:
    B(const char* const x, const char* const y, const char* const z) : 
                         X_(x), Y_(y), Z_(z) {}
private:
    const char *const X_ = nullptr;
    const char *const Y_ = nullptr;
    const char *const Z_ = nullptr;

};

class D : public B{
public:
      D() : B("X","Y","Z") {}
};

class D1 : public B{}; //Similar to D
```

Now, I want to use this class/classes as template for functions present in another class :

```
class S {

public:

template<class T>
int S1(some args);

};

template<class T>
int S::S1(some args) {
  //Do something based on template non-static member
  if(T::getX() == "X") //Getting error here -- illegal call of non-static member function 
  {}
}
```

Calling this function like below :

```
std::unique_ptr<S> s_ptr;
int rval = s_ptr->S1<D>();
```

1. Is it possible to achieve this kind of functionality?
2. Better way of doing things?

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: No, you can't use non-static member functions without an instance of the class. I mean, what would you expect `return X_` to do, when there is no instance of `D` that would contain an `X_`? Do maybe want to make them static? Or do you have an instance of `D` that you could pass to `S1`? In the end you must decide where the data should come from (static or from an instance).

Comment: How to achieve this functionality then ?

Comment: You don't achieve this, because it's not possible the way you want. Do you understand the difference between static and non-static member functions? To call a non-static member function you need an instance of the class. I think that's mostly a design problem. Will the values be the same for all instances of `D` or will they be the different?

Comment: What functionality?  @churill has already explained what the problem is, how are you going to fix it?

Comment: I understood the problem. @churill : The values would be different for D and any other derived class. What I want to achieve is to probably somehow make decision based on types present in template class.

Comment: I have lot of duplicate code. For every class type -- we are having same code written 5 times which does not make sense and I wanted to use templates to substitute values based on type.

Comment: Why you are not creating an instance of `T` before calling `getX()`? I mean, instead of 'if(T::getX() == "X")' you can have `if(T{}.getX() == "X")`. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here was not to go with non-static type but rather I could achieve this by using CRTP.

```
#include <string>

class Types {};

template <typename T>
class BaseTempl : public Types {
    public:
    static std::string A;
    static std::string B;
    static std::string C;
    static std::string D;
};


class Derived1 : public BaseTempl<Derived1> {
};

template <>
std::string BaseTempl<Derived1>::A = "A-Derived1";
template <>
std::string BaseTempl<Derived1>::B = "B-Derived1";
template <>
std::string BaseTempl<Derived1>::C = "C-Derived1";
template <>
std::string BaseTempl<Derived1>::D = "D-Derived1";

class Derived2 : public BaseTempl<Derived2> {
};

template <>
std::string BaseTempl<Derived2>::A = "A-Derived2";
template <>
std::string BaseTempl<Derived2>::B = "B-Derived2";
template <>
std::string BaseTempl<Derived2>::C = "C-Derived2";
template <>
std::string BaseTempl<Derived2>::D = "D-Derived2";
```

This allowed me to use polymorphic user-defined-class as template parameters and then use values inside these user-defined-template-type for some decision making.